# Android Mediaplayer won't load

Tags: android, service, path, media-player

I have a class which calls this service class to play the media player

```
 class MusicService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener {
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

   @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
 return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.s);// raw/s.mp3
  mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
  }

 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
  mediaPlayer.start();
  }
return START_STICKY;
 }

public void onDestroy() {
   if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
   mediaPlayer.stop();
   }
   mediaPlayer.release();
 }

   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
 stopSelf();
 }

}
```

I don't want it to load the raw file i want it to load a path which a string in the class that calls this service.

```
 String path = "path is here"

 private void playAudio(String url) throws Exception{
 Intent music = new Intent(this,MusicService.class);
 intent.putExtra("paths",path)
 startService(music);
```

How would i go about doing this...

The music file comes from the sd card

Comment: where is your music file stored?

Comment: So what is your problem, music is not playing or getting any exception?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this---------

```
MediaPlayer md=new MediaPlayer();
        md.prepare();
        md.setDataSource(path);
```

Comment: Yea except when they exit that screen pick a new song and it loads the screen again now both music player are playing over each other

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are you doing in your activity but, If your are just passing a music file path in service and then want to start media player in service then I think you have to try something like this,

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer; 
     String musicFile;

    @Override        
    public void onCreate() {        
       mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
       mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);        
     }   
    @Override   
    onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)        {          
      musicFile=intent.getExtra("paths"); 
    try {

            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(musicFile);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
     if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) 
       {             
        mediaPlayer.start();             
        } 
      return START_STICKY;     
     }
```

Comment: after setDatacource you have to put prepare method.When you are going to play,check the player is already set path  set  and playing.